# How to store text file data as a two dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to read and store the data in a text file as a 2D array but I'm not really sure how to do it... Please help!
The data in the file is as such:

```
Iver Heath
32 110.0 57.0

High Wycombe
35 235.0 121.0

Datchet
12 78.0 38.0

Englefield Green
12 278.0 157.0

Uxbridge
12 123.0 57.0
```

....and so on

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
$file = array_filter(array_map("trim", file("branches.txt")), "strlen");
        print_r($file) . '</br>';
```

[this gives me a standard array like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVOd6.png)

I need to keep the indices with the location names at the first level and then turn each index with the three values into separate indices in an array within the first level `arrays([1] within [0], [4] within [3], etc)`

Comment: can you post what you have done ?

Comment: You want like the first line will be index and the second one will be value from the file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow. Please visit the help center and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Comment: @Saurabh I've edited it to include what I've tried now, apologies :)

Comment: @theinarasu I've edited it to include what I've tried now, apologies :)

Answer (score 0):

You could parse it using [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) :

```
foreach(file($filename) as $lineNumber => $lineContent){
   //do something depending of $lineNumber
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the sample data, the data structure should be as follows:-

`Location[line break]Number of property[space]Income[space]Expenditure[line break][line break]`

Parser:-

```
// config
$line_break = "\r\n";
$path_to_file = "path/to/file";

// read file content,
$data = file_get_contents("$path_to_file");

// split data to array of records
$data = explode("{$line_break}{$line_break}", $data);

// split record to fields,
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    $data[$i] = explode("{$line_break}", trim($data[$i]), 2);
    list($data[$i][1], $data[$i][2], $data[$i][3])  = explode(' ', trim($data[$i][1]), 3);
}
```

Note:-

1. Change $line_break ("\r\n" for Windows, "\r" for Mac OS, "\n" for Unix/Linux") and $path_to_file accordingly
2. This is just a simple parser without filter. So please make sure your raw
   data has consistent data structure.

Hope this helps.